# Geoserver WMS layers default to off

Tags: geoserver

When users add my WMS server to their ArcGIS client, the first 10 layers are enabled by default and the others are disabled by default. Is it possible to set Geoserver so the WMS has all layers disabled by default?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

GeoServer (and any other WMS server) does not control the visibility of the layers in the client. You need to check the ArcGIS documentation to see how to control WMS layers.